# MySQL stored procedure - access returned column value

Tags: mysql, t-sql, stored-procedures

How do I do this?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `MyProcedure`(
IN param VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    SELECT id, column2, column3
    FROM table1
    WHERE column5 = param;
    LIMIT 1;

    IF (FOUND_ROWS() > 0) THEN
        UPDATE table1 SET column4 = 1 WHERE id = theIdFromRowAbove;
    END IF;
END
```

I want my stored procedure to select a row from table1, and if a row is found, update table1 where the id = the id from the found row. I have been searching the internet but still can't seem to figure it out. I'm not exactly sure what to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a variable and set its value false after find row set true

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `MyProcedure`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE find_row INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE theIdFromRowAbove INT DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT id, column2, column3, 1 INTO theIdFromRowAbove, @column2, @column3, find_row
    FROM table1
    WHERE id = 5
    LIMIT 1;

    IF (find_row) THEN
        UPDATE table1 SET column4 = 1 WHERE id = theIdFromRowAbove;
    END IF;
END
```

for more info about `SELECT....INTO` [Official Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html)

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to write it for simplicity, but apparently I goofed. I updated the SQL.

Comment: Note that I also need to still return the SELECT.

Comment: in above first query, you can add other columns in select query

Comment: But how do I do this?: UPDATE table1 SET column4 = 1 WHERE id = theIdFromRowAbove;